# Where are Ktorrent magnet-links located?

Tags: bittorrent, ktorrent

I'm currently running KTorrent on Ubuntu, and I'm making a switch to qBittorrent. I can pull the unfinished torrents file without issue, but in the programs "magnet downloader" I have a list of magnets that haven't become torrent files yet. Does anyone know where in the file system those magnet links are located, so I can move them to qBittorrent?

Answer (score 1):

FOUND IT! ! ! ! ! !
/home/ user name /.local/share/ktorrent in that folder a file of Magnets, in that file the language is a bit odd.

```
stoppedi0e6:silenti0e5:group0:8:location0:18:move_on_completion0:ed6:magnet290
```

remove that junk. starting at "magnet:?xt=urn" to the next junk, thats the link you'll have to add to the new torrent client.

Comment: I don't think that advice is accurate any more: my magnets file is a month and a half old.  Perhaps something changed about how ktorrent records pending magnet links?